# c# sending data from excel to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I want to be able to send data from an excel file to an SQL database.

The Excel file only has one column and will always be this way.

I am currently working on a project where people will place excel files into a folder which will need to be read and put into sql, I am able to monitor the folder currently and am able to capture the file name of that file to a variable which i can call to select the excel file.

What i cannot find is a simple excel to sql tutorial that doesnt rely on the import wizard.

If you are able to help please do and if you want any further information please feel free to ask

Thanks alot :)

Comment: SSIS packages do this perfectly and you can loop through a directory and import each file in that directory.

Comment: Hi brad, ive taken a look at this but do you know any in particular that would help?  im incredibly out of my depth and would love to learn more about this

Comment: That is a big topic, but here is an article to get you started:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/